# Run iOS Apps on iPhone with iOS 8 through XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

My iphone is currently running ios 8. When I try to run apps through XCode on my phone I get this error message:

```
Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
```

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

In XCode under deployment target, there is no option for 8.0 (iOS 8) and the app will not run on my phone.

Is there an SDK I need to download for xcode?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would Xcode 5 know about iOS 8 to list it as a deployment target? You need to get Xcode 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download Xcode 6, which includes the iOS 8 SDK.  You would download this from the Apple developer site, where you downloaded the iOS 8 Beta image from.

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: I have a paid subscription to the iOS dev membership..would i need to be a mac developer as well to download iOS 6 .. (would i need Yosemite beta)?

Comment: Nope, you just need to log in and download Xcode where it says "Xcode 6 beta 2" when you switch to the iOS 8 Beta tab in the developer center.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 5 knows nothing of the existence of iOS 8. You're going to need to get Xcode 6 from [this page](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#) ([direct link](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_2_i8z2ly/xcode_6_beta_2.dmg)) if you want to run apps on your iOS 8 device.

**Note** that the direct link is only good for the version of Xcode 6 shipped alongside iOS 8 Beta 2. I have no idea what it will do when we get to Beta 3.

Answer (score 1):

The way I got it to work was:

1. close all instances of Xcode.
2. open the Xcode 6-Beta
3. open Xcode 5 so both Xcode's are running at the same time
4. close Xcode 6-Beta, and after doing that, Xcode 5 will recognize your device as a capable one and you'll be able to deploy to your iOS 8 phone.

The reason you need Xcode 5 is because you won't be able to submit iOS 7 apps to the app store from Xcode 6, it'll give you an error so you need to use Xcode 5.

Comment: are you running mavericks or Yosemite? .. would i need to upgrade to Yosemite beta for xcode 6?

Comment: @user3207650, I'm running Mavericks, the minimum software version for Xcode 6 is 10.9 so if you have Mavericks you're fine.

Comment: Just to confirm, I needed to use my iPad (with iOS8) for testing an older app that will not build in xCode 6. Opening xCode 6 then opening xCode 5 with my project allows it to recognize the device. Took me a while to figure out why it would show up sometimes and not others. This seems to be the key. I'm working in Yosemite.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Tried various combinations. I'm on xcode6-beta6 and Mavericks.

Comment: @amergn was isn't working? Deploying or getting Xcode 5 to recognize your device?